# Tracking Urls User Has Visited During A Session

Tags: asp.net

I have an app with alot of anchor tags in it. I wanna see what ones a user clicked on during a session. I thought aspnet automatically saved that information here:

```
string sessID =  System.Web.SessionState.SessionID;
```

But there is no such thing as SessionID in the SessionState namespace. Is this information saved automatically, if so how do I access it?

Here is my simple html

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    Page 2
    <a href="http://www.w3schools.com/">Visit W3Schools</a>
    <br />
    <a href="http://www.yahoo.com/">Yahoos</a>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless those anchors are not for client side manipulation only and they induce a round-trip to the server, the IIS log is the place to look for such information.

The following example shows an IIS log file entry, as viewed in a text editor:

```
192.168.114.201, -, 03/20/01, 7:55:20, W3SVC2, SERVER, 172.21.13.45, 4502, 163, 3223, 200, 0, GET, /DeptLogo.gif, -,
```

You will be able to get all requests your users make on the server, so you simply need to parse the log to get the info that you need. More info [here](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/c93b2856-76c4-4348-9d46-8a60612c3b23.mspx?mfr=true)

For other solutions see:

- [Creating an activity log](http://forums.asp.net/t/1396876.aspx/1)
- [Tracking User Activity](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/Tracking-User-Activity.aspx)